# Yii - Printing the table content

Tags: php, yii

In my single page i have 2 tables. First table is the basic info table. And in other i will have list of lists to be order. I want print only the second table. How to do it.

Its not the basic print, with print button i want print the content of the second table alone.

Here is the code, am able to print the second table but css is not getting applied and its not printing as its in the screen.

```
<script language="javascript">
    function printDiv(divName) {
       var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
       var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;

       document.body.innerHTML = printContents;

       window.print();

       document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
    }
</script> 
<table width="100%" class="ticketpopup"  id='first'>
<tr>
    <td class='label-column' width="100">Address1</td>
    <td class='value-column' width="200" ><?echo $Address1?></td>
    <td class='label-column' width="100">Address2</td>
    <td class='value-column' width="200"><?echo $Address2?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class='label-column' width="100">Suburb</td>
    <td class='value-column' width="200" ><?echo $Suburb?></td>
    <td class='label-column' width="100">State</td>
    <td class='value-column' width="200"><?echo $State?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class='label-column' width="100">Postcode</td>
    <td class='value-column' width="200" ><?echo $Postcode?></td>
    <td class='label-column' width="100">Telephone1</td>
    <td class='value-column' width="200"><?echo $Telephone1?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class='label-column' width="100">FAX    </td>
    <td class='value-column' width="200" ><?echo $FAX?></td>
    <td class='label-column' width="100">ISPCode</td>
    <td class='value-column' width="200"><?echo $ISPCode?></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td class='label-column' width="100">Email</td>
    <td class='value-column' width="200" ><?echo $Email?></td>
    <td class='label-column' width="100">PosSoftware</td>
    <td class='value-column' width="200"><?echo $PosSoftware?></td>
</tr>
</table>
<table id="second">
<?  
for ($i=0;$i<10;$i++)
{ 
      print "<tr><td class='label-column' width='100'>Item Name</td>
             <td class='value-column' width='200'><?echo $value[$i];?></td>";
}
?>
</table>

<a href="javascript:void(printDiv('second'));">Print</a>
```

Comment: Well, show please source code where u try to did for show only second table.

Comment: I edit the question. Please check

Comment: Sorry, some mess, i did it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with jQuery:

```
// You can use var w = window.open('blank.html', 'print'); 
var w = window.open('about:blank', 'print'); 
// Copy your second table
$(w.document.body).html('<table>'+$('#second').html()+'</table>');
w.print();
```